# Converting a list of elements to asteriks

Tags: python

How do I convert a list of elements to asterisks?

```
def converter (input):
  int_to_list = [(x) for x in str(input)]
  if len(int_to_list) == 16:
    first_12_digit = int_to_list[0 : 12]
    list_to_int_1 = ''.join(first_12_digit)
    print(list_to_int_1)

    last_4_digit = int_to_list[12 : 16]
    list_to_int_2 = ''.join(last_4_digit)
    print(list_to_int_2)
```

I am trying to convert all of the elements of the list `first_12_digit` to asterisks, an example output will be `["*","*","*","*".....]`. Is there a way to do it using list comprehension?

Comment: `int_to_list[0 : 12] = ["*"] * 12` should work. If you want a list of 12 `"*"` a fast way is to multiply a list of a single element by 12.

Comment: `newlist = ['*' for _ in first_12_digit]`??

Comment: `newlist = list('*'*len(first_12_digit))`